# C# Extract part of the string that starts with specific letters

Tags: c#, regex, string, substring, startswith

I have a string which I extract from an HTML document like this:

```
    var elas = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//a[@class='a-size-small a-link-normal a-text-normal']");
    if (elas != null)
   {
   //
     _extractedString = elas.Attributes["href"].Value;
   }
```

The HREF attribute contains this part of the string:

```
gp/offer-listing/B002755TC0/
```

And I'm trying to extract the `B002755TC0` value, but the problem here is that the string will vary by its length and I cannot simply use Substring method that C# offers to extract that value...

Instead I was thinking if there's a clever way to do this, to perhaps a match beginning of the string with what I search?

For example I know for a fact that each href has this structure like I've shown, So I would simply match these keywords:

```
offer-listing/
```

So I would find this keyword and start extracting the part of the string `B002755TC0` until the next " / " sign ?

Can someone help me out with this ?

Comment: You can totally use a regular expression here.

Comment: @Pac0 could you show me an example ? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a perfect job for a [regular expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expressions) :

```
string text = "gp/offer-listing/B002755TC0/";

Regex pattern = new Regex(@"offer-listing/(\w+)/");

Match match = pattern.Match(text);
string whatYouAreLookingFor = match.Groups[1].Value;
```

Explanation : we just match the exact pattern you need.

- 'offer-listing/'
- followed by any combination of (at least one) 'word characters' (letters, digits, hyphen, etc...),
- followed by a slash.

The parenthesis `()` mean 'capture this group' (so we can extract it later with match.Groups[1]).

---

EDIT: if you want to extract also from this :  `/dp/B01KRHBT9Q/`

Then you could use this pattern :

```
Regex pattern = new Regex(@"/(\w+)/$");
```

which will match both this string and the previous. The `$` stands for the end of the string, so this literally means :

*capture the characters in between the last two slashes of the string*

Comment: Yes yes this is it, it' works perfectly !! =) Thanks you so much !

Comment: hey what about a case where HREF looks like this:  /dp/B01KRHBT9Q/ ?

Comment: then you can use this pattern : `@"/dp/(\w+)/"` . However, if you want to have a pattern that matches all the possibilities, you should explain a bit more, so we can find something in common among all the possibilities. For instance : is the pattern you want to capture always at the end the HREF ?

Comment: or : is the part you want to capture always starting with a capital letter whilst the rest of the url is not ?

Comment: what would happen if there's more than one match?

Comment: @MohammedSohailEbrahim I'm not sure how there can be several matches here, as `\w` cannot match `/`, and the regex is anchored at the end of the string with `$`. But in general, if there are several matches with a regular expression, you'll get the first one  with `.Match()`, or you can iterate through all matches by using `.Matches()`.

Answer (score 2):

Though there is already an accepted answer, I thought of sharing another solution, without using Regex. Just find the position of your pattern in the input + it's lenght, so the wanted text will be the next character. to find the end, search for the first "/" after the begining of the wanted text:

```
string input = "gp/offer-listing/B002755TC0/";
string pat = "offer-listing/";
int begining = input.IndexOf(pat)+pat.Length;
int end = input.IndexOf("/",begining);
string result = input.Substring(begining,end-begining);
```

If your desired output is always the last piece, you could also use split and get the last non-empty piece:

```
string result2 = input.Split(new string[]{"/"},StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
  .ToList().Last();
```